# How to use client script from suitlet?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

My issue is like that:

I have the inventory detail sub record window, I did an iframe to change the view there and replaced it with my suitelet, in my suitelet I upload a file or simple text and then I want to use that values to change the record that I came from (the record is on creating not edit mode)
is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a client script for your Suitelet. like below:

```
                        // Creating the form.
                        var form = serverWidget.createForm({
                            title: 'Suitelet Title',
                            hideNavBar: false
                        });
                       //Adding the Client script (I used a relative path)
                        form.clientScriptModulePath = './YourClientScript.js';
```